# Хук функции в dll C++

Tags: c++, функции, hook

Всем привет! Может ли кто помочь, с этим? Нужно захукать одну функцию в dll, чтоб когда она вызвалась я мог подставить свою функцию. Я пытался это делать, но как то бестолку. Ничего не сработало. Кто может показать простой пример. 
Ида расскажу как я делал, сперва я инжектился к процессу, чтобы в это время перехватить с dll ф-ии.. И кст имеет ли значение x64 x86?

Comment: Джефри Рихтер. Описывает весь метод в своей известной книге. Код там же есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Вызывается, чтобы иметь возможность писать в область памяти по указателю ptr
void Unprotect(void *ptr, int count)
{
    DWORD protect;
    VirtualProtect(ptr, count, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &protect);
}

// from - адрес функции, которую хукать
// to - адрес функции для подмены
void Jmp(size_t from, size_t to) 
{
    Unprotect((void*)from, 5);
    *(unsigned char*)from = 0xE9;
    *(int*)(from + 1) = (int)(to - (from + 5));
}
```

Это код для полной подмены вызова функции. Сигнатуры функций для хука и оригинальной обязаны совпадать.

Если нужно вернуться в оригинальную функцию после хука, то придётся лезть в `asm`код и делать `asm`вставку, уникальную для каждой функции (команды, которые были затерты `jmp`ом, автоматически сами себя не перепишут)