# Как приостановить процесс по условию вызова процессом конкретной API

Tags: c++

Создаваемая программа запускает внешнюю prog.exe. В процессе её загрузки необходимо отследить момент вызова определённой API (например, `GetCommandLineW`) и приостановить процесс. Во время остановки будут выполняться команды, затем остановленный процесс надо возобновить далее с того же места, где был остановлен.
Фактически это полный аналог ручной процедуры остановки процесса по break point в отладчике и затем его возобновления (типа: F9 > bp (API) > изменение кода > F9).
Схема создаваемой программы:

```
int main()  
{
    STARTUPINFO SI;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION PI;

    ZeroMemory( &SI, sizeof(SI) );
    SI.cb = sizeof(SI);
    ZeroMemory( &PI, sizeof(PI) );

      if( !CreateProcess( NULL, "prog.exe", NULL, NULL,
                         FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &SI, &PI ))
    (printf( "CreateProcess failed \n" ));
      else (printf( "OK... \n" ));
//-------------------------------------------------------------  
// Здесь требуется вставка, приостанавливающая процесс prog.exe  
// по условию вызова процессом API (например, GetCommandLineW)  
//-------------------------------------------------------------  
// Здесь производится WriteProcessMemory    
//-------------------------------------------------------------   
// Здесь требуется вставка, возобновляющая процесс prog.exe  
//-------------------------------------------------------------  
}
```

Comment: это уже не чистый с++. А с кодо-ассемблерными вставками. Без знания ассемблера не выйдет. Найдите готовые примеры перехвата функций и допилите их. За вас решение под конкретно вашу задачу вам врядли напишут. У вас также отсутствует запрос по-привилегиям... адресная привязка... может ещё чего не хватает. Лучше таки взять готовое решение.

Comment: Я намеренно не использовал слово "перехват", т.к был уверен, что меня сразу пошлют делать хук. Так, собственно, и произошло. В данном случае, IMHO, всё должно быть проще, ибо мне не надо делать инъекцию кода, что предполагают все варианты хуков.

Comment: Вам сюда: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809754.aspx

Comment: У вас насамом деле много "возможностей". 1. Вы можете "сгенить" простой переход по jmp, но нужно считаться с компилятором - смотреть поддерживает ли он `__declspec(naked)` - безфреймовую процедуру, считаться с видом стекового фрейма который сгенится. 2. Вы можете сами загрузить програму и сами линковать её - тоже достаточно трудоёмкая задача.  3. @Vlad предложил вам хороший вариант - воспользоваться возможностями Debug API - с ними нужно тоже разбираться.

Comment: Вот похожий вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543404/17974